# How To Add Another SmartTarget Toolbar Icon to Content Manager

Tags: 2011, gui-extensions, content-manager, smarttarget

When integrating SmartTarget with Content Manager, a toolbar icon is created to provide a single sign-on capability.  I would like to add another SmartTarget icon to the CM toolbar, pointing to a different SmartTarget Index Server instance (different port #).  On the Content Delivery side, we have more than one deployer.  Can someone outline the steps needed to create an extension that would support an additional toolbar icon in CM for SmartTarget?  Each icon should be uniquely identifiable by its icon text value.  Perhaps someone has already done this?

Comment: Just a note that from SmartTarget 2014 onward this button is no longer available - but its replacement supports multiple instances natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks John and Boris for pointing me in the right direction.  I was able to successfully create a second SmartTarget toolbar icon in CME 2011 using the following methodology:

NOTE: ~ = <TRIDION_HOME> location

1. Rename **~/web/SmartTarget** folder to **~/web/SmartTarget1** and clone the folder as needed by incrementing the numeric suffix.
2. Edit **~/web/SmartTargetN/SmartTarget.xml** and change the *fredhopperUrl* attribute value.
3. In the **~/web/WebUI/Editors/SDLTools/Scripts** folder, copy/rename the **smarttarget.js** resource to have a numeric suffix (same as step 1).  Update **smarttargetN.js**, adding the same numeric suffix (N) to:

   - **SDLTools.Commands.OpenSmartTarget** commandset object and method prototypes
   - *Interface* Name
   - *smarttargeturl* configuration property
4. In the **~/web/WebUI/Editors/SDLTools/Theme** folder, copy/rename the **smarttarget.css** resource to have a numeric suffix (same as step1).  Update all **SmartTargetBtn** id values in **smarttargetN.css**, adding the same numeric suffix.
5. In the **~/web/WebUI/Editors/SDLTools/Configuration/SDLTools.config**, add the same numeric suffix (N) to the following:

   - Resource groups:

     - **SDLTools.SmartTarget**

       - Update smarttarget.css reference
       - Update commandset reference
     - **SDLTools.SmartTarget.Commandset**

       - Update smarttarget.js reference
   - Ribbon Toolbar Button Extension

     - assignid attribute
     - command element value
     - resource dependency
   - Commands

     - *commandset* id attribute
     - *command* name and implementation attributes
     - *dependency* value
   - Settings

     - *smarttargeturl* element name and value

Answer (score 1):

The SmartTarget Toolbar Icon (and XML configuration) is simply a GUI extension.  I suspect it's possible to reuse the tool (you'll have to configure it again under a different path) or use the existing implementation to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar Button always comes in pair with Command, which will be executed by click on Button. Here is nice [video](http://tridion.uibeardcore.com/2013/07/toolbar/) which explains how to create Toolbar extension. In your extension you will need to add the same Toolbar Button, as Smart Target do, and slightly modified Command.
To find out how SmartTarget Toolbar Button works, look into SmartTarget configuration file (`Tridion/web/WebUI/Editors/SmartTarget/Configuration/Editor.config`)